# Having trouble understanding node.js listeners

Tags: node.js

I'm working on two node.js tutorials at the moment and while I understand what is going on within each tutorial, I clearly don't understand what's going on **that** well.

The following code listens for "data" events and then adds new chunks of data to a variable named postData. Another listener sends this data along with other stuff to my route.js file.

```
  request.addListener("data", function  (postDataChunk) {
        postData += postDataChunk;
        console.log("Received POST data chunk '" + postDataChunk + "'.");
    });

    request.addListener("end", function  () {
        route(handle, pathname, response, postData);
    });
```

The following code creates a variable, tailChild, that spawns the shell command 'tail' on my system log and then attempts to add this data to my postData variable:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var tail_child = spawn('tail', ['-f', '/var/log/system.log']);
    tail_child.stdout.on('data', function  (data) {
        postData += data;
        console.log("TAIL READING: " + data);
    });
tail_child.stdout.on('end', function  () {
        route(handle, pathname, response, postData);
    });
```

Now my console is updated in realtime with system.log data but my browser times out with a "No data received error."

I've tried tweaking the code above to figure what is going wrong and as near as I can tell node is telling me that var data is null so it is adding nothing to var postData. This doesn't make sense to me since `console.log("TAIL READING: " + data)` gives me the results of `spawn('tail', ['-f', '/var/log/system.log'])` in my terminal window. Clearly var data is not null.

**Edit:**
[Here's a pastebin link to my server.js code](http://pastebin.com/3rvFTZXm/)

Comment: Can you show the whole code? I don't see any mistake in your snippets?

Comment: Raynos, all of my code is spread out over several files. Do you just want my server.js code? These snippets are from server.js

Comment: @somas1 you should not have two `end` listeners nor should you have two calls to `route`

Comment: where do you call the response.end?

Comment: @Raynos, thanks for the notes about my improper use of end and route.

Comment: @jcolebrand, I didn't call response.end in the context of spawn("tail") Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @jcolebrand @somas1 I do hope you call `response.end()` in `route`.

Comment: I don't care _where_ it gets called so long as _that_ it gets called

Comment: @Raynos, I have a requestHandlers.js file that is called by route. That file has several functions that are called by route when appropriate. Only one of these functions is ever called and each except the one handling spawn('tail' ...) calls response.end. I've fixed that now. I think, I'll be able to fix my issues with the pointers you guys have given me.

Comment: @somas1 might want to use connect for some of this functionality (or express)

Comment: I'm not sure what connect is yet but regarding express, I want to understand a little more of how node.js works before trying out a framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tail -f won't trigger the end callback so you never respond to the user.

Comment: That's interesting. I'll look at the tutorial I drew that code from and see how it was handled.